# Bulk data update in Salesforce from External System

Tags: rest-api, bulk-api

I have got a requirement to update 6k records in Salesforce from external system in every 4 hours.  Can you please suggest what would be best way for this .

1) Should I use the standard Bulk API  ? How to handle all batch process that will be created ?

2) Is SOAP a good option too? I know , it's not in much use nowadays.

3) Can I think of REST in HTTP Post as well for this much of data ?

Please advice the best approach.

P.S. I can't use a middleware integration tool.

Comment: One more thing to confirm. If I make a rest call from external system to update the SFDC records , it'll be synchronous... right ?? and , I am restricted to 6 MB for request siz.e

Answer (score 1):

Since 6k is not a big data volume, you can go for either bulk API or SOAP API. But please give first preference to Bulk API. Details regarding how to implement Bulk API can be found in below link,

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Loading_Large_Data_Sets_with_the_Force.com_Bulk_API

SOAP API also can be used. For connecting with SOAP API also there is lot of examples in developerforce. Checkout below link to get details regarding all APIs

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_what_is_api.htm

Comment: Thanks Victor.  I think , I can go with REST as well if the request size is less than 6 MB. One thing to confirm. if I make a rest call from external system to update the SFDC records , it'll be synchronous... right ??